# Relations from a set to set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ be a set. Let $Y = \{5, 6, 7, 8\}$ be another set. Define relation $R$ as $R = \{(2, 8), (4, 7), (1, 5)\}$.

Then $2 R 8$, $4 R 7$, $1 R 5$.

Here $R$ is both a relation between the components of ordered pairs and the set of ordered pairs related under a certain operation.

Am I understanding it correctly? What's $R$, actually? Why is it used differently in differnt contexts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, $R$ is formally defined as a subset of $X \times Y$. However, we use the notation $xRy$ to mean $(x,y) \in R$. The two are strictly equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Because there is a "common sense" tradition according to which a *relation* is ... a relation.

If you consider the relation "__*is father of*...", we usually write : "Paul *is father of* John".

This "tradition" is still used in current mathematical practice when we write : $n < m$ to signify that "$n$ is less than $m$".

Thus, more or less a century ago, the first "symbolization" of relations was :

> $xRy$.

Only after the development of modern set-theory, the genial idea of [Wiener](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norbert_Wiener) in 1914 and [Kuratowski](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazimierz_Kuratowski) in 1921 to "encode" the concept of [ordered pair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair) in set-theoretic language, permitted the "reduction" of relations to sets, i.e. a relation is a set of *ordered pairs*.

Thus, we have that : if the *relation* $R$ is defined on the set $S$, i.e. $R \subseteq S \times S$, then:

> $xRy \text { iff } \langle x,y \rangle \in R$.

Comment: Hi Mauro, quick question on terminology: given $xRy$, could we read this as "$R$ relates $x$ to $y$"? I understand the most common way of reading $xRy$ is "$x$ is $R$-related to $y$", but regardless I would still appreciate your input :-).

Comment: @TaylorRendon - yes, we can. The usual way is "$x$ is less-than $y$" but we may also say that "the less-than relation relates $x$ to $y$".